# How to throw exceptions on Java/Spring controller connected to Mongo repository?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-restcontroller, spring-repositories

I am getting more familiar with Spring Boot and to do so, I am building a REST api which is connected to a mongo db, therefore I am using a Mongo Repository. I have this endpoint on my controller which is responsible for deleting a resource (expert in this case) from my database:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/experts")
class ExpertController {
    @Autowired
    private  ExpertRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void deleteExpert(@PathVariable ObjectId id) {
        repository.delete(repository.findBy_id(id));
    }

} }
```

My question is how could I throw an exception in case the `id` of the resource which is added does not exist on the database? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `throw new MyCustomIdNotFoundException();`

Just make sure you mark your controller method as throwing that exception.

You can then handle that exception using Spring's exception handling tools, a good article on which is available at: https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring